# How to Trap Errors in a PHP MySQL Transaction with Rollback

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, try-catch, rollback

I have a transaction that does an insert into several tables.  I want to catch any errors so that if any of the inserts fail they will all be rolled back.  Here is a short version of what I am trying to do:

```
try {
    $this->conn->beginTransaction();
    //build an sql insert...
    $sql = "INSERT INTO...
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    //do more inserts...

    //commit the transaction
    $this->conn->commit();

    $this->message = 'The Program has been added.';

    //catch errors and rollback
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->message = $e->getMessage();
        $this->conn->rollBack();
    }
```

All of the inserts work properly but if there is a problem, I don't seem to be catching the error and the rollback does not happen.  For instance, if I write bad sql or don't pass values for parameters, I just get php errors but the inserts proceed anyway.  I can post the full code if it helps but maybe it is something obvious?

Comment: Have you turned PDO exceptions on? If not sure, add `$this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` (assuming your conn is pdo instance).

Comment: that did the trick, it was actually $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Oh, I did it wrong should be `PDO::` once :)